# I am having trouble understanding IO.read as ruby parameter

Tags: ruby, io

I am examining the madlib exercise on rubyquiz and ran into a line that I don't understand:

```
madlib = Madlib.new(IO.read(ARGV.shift))
```

I've done a healthy amount of googling but haven't found anything helpful.
I'm not sure what to do.

```
madlib = Madlib.new(IO.read(ARGV.shift))
answers = []
madlib.list_questions do |i, q|
  print "Give me " + q + ": "
  answers[i] = gets.strip
end
answers.each_index {|i| madlib.answer_question(i, answers[i]) }
puts madlib.show_result
```

Comment: You question is unclear. In fact, you don't even have a question! There's just a statement. What is your actual question?

Answer (score 3):

## Short version

It sends the content of the file specified as argument (`ruby script.rb file.txt`) to `Madlib.new`, as a single string.

## Longer version

#### ARGV.shift

```
madlib = Madlib.new(IO.read(ARGV.shift))
```

`ARGV.shift` is the first argument after `ruby script.rb`. For :

```
ruby script.rb some_text_file.txt
```

it is `some_text_file.txt`.

Note that `ARGV.shift` also removes the first argument from `ARGV`. The next time `ARGV.shift` is called, it will return the second arguments after `ruby script.rb`.

#### IO.read()

`IO.read('file.txt')` reads the entire content of `file.txt`, and returns it as a String.

Since `File` inherits from `IO` and the example here reads a file, it could also be written `File.read(filename)`.

#### Madlib.new()

The string returned by `IO.read` is sent to `Madlib.new`

Comment: Thanks, I was finally able to get it working on my machine. Nice to have a human explain things...

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple, indeed.

`IO.read` is there to read a file whose name is in the array ARGV containing the parameters passed to this Ruby program.

The sequence is:

1. A parameter is passed containing a filename. This parameter will be in ARGV array;
2. `ARV.shift` returns the first element of ARGV array, the file name;
3. This parameter is then received by `IO.read`, that reads the corresponding file and returns its contents; and,
4. Finally, these contents are received by `Madlib.new`, which creates a Madnew instance based on them.

As you may see, the real parameter passed to `Madlib.new` is the result of `IO.read`, not `IO.read` itself.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. Very helpful!